# How to get the value of a drop down selected value with the parent as the selected element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, parent

History:

I'm using the children method because I'll be looping through `div`s that have content in them that is dynamically generated by the user, so there's no way of me knowing how many divs there will be. If there is another method I should be using, by all means, show me :)

I'm having trouble here using the following code:

```
$("[name = listItem]").each( function (){
var z = $(this).children("[name='dropDown'] option:selected").val();
alert(z);
});
```

In this example the output would be an alert box with:

```
undefined
```

It's strange because this way bellow works fine!

```
var z = $("[name='dropDown'] option:selected").val();
alert(z);
```

the output for this would be the appropriate value:

```
1
```

for the `children()` method, I thought you could use the standard selector syntax. What do you think?

Comment: Uhh, usually you'd use $('select').val(); to get value from select field;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("[name = listItem]").each( function (){
    var z = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    alert(z);
});
```

Or:

```
$("[name='dropDown'] option:selected").each( function (){
    var z = $(this).val();
    alert(z);
});
```

But i am a bit confused as to what `listItem` & `dropDown` are...

Comment: Thank you for your response, The first example worked like gold! thank you Jleagle!

Comment: oh, btw, `listItem` is an array of `div`s and a `dropDown` is a `select` element.